# Avoiding a newline when using fprintf with time.h

Tags: c, printf, time.h

I keep getting a new line printed **after** the current time is written to a log.txt file. In this example I want the time and logMessage printed on the same line. Could you point me in the right direction as to what I'm missing here?

The logWrite function is called from the main function:

```
strcpy(logMessage, "**********RESTART**********");
logWrite(logMessagePtr);
```

The logWrite function is:

```
void logWrite(char * logMessagePtr)
{
    /* Initialise time variables for log file. */
    int hours, minutes, seconds, day, month, year;
    // time_t is an arithmetic time type
    time_t now;
    // Update current time using time(&now);
    time(&now);

    FILE * logFilePtr;

    logFilePtr = fopen ("C:\\log.txt", "a");
    if (logFilePtr != NULL)
    {
        fprintf(logFilePtr, ("%s", ctime(&now)));
        fprintf(logFilePtr, "%s", logMessagePtr);
        fprintf(logFilePtr,"\n");
        fclose(logFilePtr);
        printf("Log file found\n"); //debug
    }
    else
    {
        perror("log.txt");
    }
}
```

The log.txt file is sucessfully (created) appended to but I consistently get a new line feed after the time is written to the file.

When I run the program twice in a row for example, the log.txt reads:

```
Sat May 22 09:16:47 2021
**********RESTART**********
Sat May 22 09:16:48 2021
**********RESTART**********
```

What I *want* is:

```
Sat May 22 09:16:47 2021 **********RESTART**********
Sat May 22 09:16:48 2021 **********RESTART**********
```

Info on [time.h](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/time_h.htm)

Comment: Off topic, but `fprintf(logFilePtr, logMessagePtr);` is dangerous; formatting in the message will be interpreted. Rather print it with `"%s"` formatting (or `fputs`).

Comment: @Arkku - good pickup, thanks. Have updated.

Comment: Also, you use `("%s", some_string)`, but that's evaluating the comma operator, and is just equivalent to `some_string`. Drop the parentheses.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasJager, updated.

Comment: You may want to consider using [`strftime`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/strftime) instead of `ctime`, as that function gives you more control on the string format, including the positions of the newline characters (and also whether any newline characters exist at all). EDIT: MikeCAT's answer which recommends the same thing beat me by exactly 1 second.

Comment: @BlackSolis This also applies to the `ctime` result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ctime(3) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ctime) says:

> The call `ctime(t)` is equivalent to `asctime(localtime(t))`. It converts the calendar time t into a null-terminated string of the form
> `"Wed Jun 30 21:49:08 1993\n"`

It looks like adding newline character is included in the specification of `ctime()`. You should use [`strftime()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime) to manually format the date and time without newline.

```
char date[128];
strftime(date, sizeof(date), "%a %b %d %T %Y", localtime(&now));
fprintf(logFilePtr, "%s", date);
```

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation of `ctime`, the string has a newline embedded. You need to remove it from consideration for printing.

Since the string returned by `ctime` has a specified format of constant width, this should accomplish that:

```
fprintf(logFilePtr, "%.24s ", ctime(&now));
```

(edit: This is assuming you wish to use `ctime` in the first place, as you do in the question. There are other, potentially better, options, such as `strftime`.)

Comment: Cheers. Answer for me is to use %.24s.

Comment: This is a fine technique, and it's one I've used myself, *but* it may be worth noting that it has a significant albeit almost impossibly remote problem: it will stop working in the year 10000. :-)

Answer (score 1):

[The `ctime` function always adds `'\n'` to the end of string](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ctime&sektion=3&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD%208.1-RELEASE). There are many different ways to solve the problem, but the easiest way is to remove this symbol. This can be done, for example, like this (based on the fact that the `ctime` ([see man](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ctime&sektion=3&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD%208.1-RELEASE)) returns `char *`, not `const char *`):

```
#include <string.h>
...
char *ctime_line = ctime (&now);
ctime_line[strlen (ctime_line) - 1] = '\0';
```

and then print this line:

```
fprintf (logFilePtr, "%s", ctime_line);
```

P.S. I do not recommend using a record like this, since the string AAA may contain, for example, the % character, which will be interpreted as a special character.

```
// bad
fprintf (logFilePtr, logMessagePtr);
// good
fprintf (logFilePtr, "%s", logMessagePtr);
```

P.P.S. The following three lines

```
fprintf (logFilePtr, "%s", ctime (&now));
fprintf (logFilePtr, "%s", logMessagePtr);
fprintf (logFilePtr, "\n");
```

can be combined into one

```
fprintf (logFilePtr, "%s %s\n", ctime (&now), logMessagePtr);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I have updated my code. I selected the %.24s answer as it still gives the option to print a newline if needed. Would upvote if I had 15 rep ;)

Comment: @BlackSolis: I believe you now have sufficient reputation. :-) Note that you can accept only one answer, but you can upvote all.